# Is it correct to use the adjective "jaded" with the preposition "with"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I was looking up the word *jaded* in various dictionaries, but couldn't find it being used with the preposition *with*. Is it correct to use the word in the following way?

> After watching the movie so many times I grew **jaded with** it.

Comment: I wouldn't expect to find it in the entry for *jaded*. This is part of a pattern involving *grow*: *grow <descriptor> with*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. In fact, that's how I would expect it to be used any time a person's jadedness is about a specific thing.